# Ubuntu 16.04.1 tells me my DNS server is 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns

Which isn't very useful.  (yes that's the local node).

I'm trying to switch from the DNS server address hardcoded into a new Comcast router to OpenDNS configured onto a secondary home wifi router and I'd like to check the result.  I've logged into opendns.com and checked the stats but have found no traffic.

```
patfla@patfla-N550JV:/etc/network$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.195.238

patfla@patfla-N550JV:/etc/network$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search SECONDARY-ROUTER-NAME
patfla@patfla-N550JV:/etc/network$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
wireless-essid   Blah           <- this hardwires me to use the secondary router
patfla@patfla-N550JV:/etc/network$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf back to its original setting.

Don't edit /etc/resolv.conf.

Instead, go to the network icon in the top panel, and select **Edit Connections**. Assuming that you're using an ethernet connect to your computer, edit the script called **Wired Connection**. Select the IPV4 tab, change the 'Method' from '**Automatic (DHCP)**' to '**Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only**' using the dropdown, and enter your desired DNS servers, comma-separated, into the box **DNS Servers**.

You can also enter the new DNS server information directly into your wifi router.

Cheers, Al

Comment: IIRC you also need to change the 'Method' from 'Automatic (DHCP)' to 'Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only' using the dropdown

Comment: @heynema  ok followed your instructions and am now waiting to see if the changes reflect on OpenDNS's stats pages.  In the sense that the stats become non-zero.

Comment: OK. Just for fun, what does your resolv.conf look like now? In terminal, typing **host -v www.buy.com**, tells you what DNS server is responding? And if you do the same command a second time? Cheers, Al

Comment: resolv.conf shows the correct addrs (208.67.220.220 and 208.67.222.222) and so does host -v www.buy.com.  Illustrating a principle from many years of software engineering: bang away at it long enough and eventually it will work.

Comment: or... giggle... just ask for help from the right person... :-)

Comment: Worked for me - had to disable and re-enable networking first though (through the network icon in the top panel) to apply the changes

Answer (score 0):

change the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf to required to test it. Say
vim /etc/resolv.conf

```
#nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This settings will be automatically cleared off on the very next reboot.

Comment: Thanks.  Saw that but decided not to use it since I'd like the DNS server address to persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

I had the the same problem on Xubuntu 17.04. After each boot up I could not go online, because there was the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/resolv.conf`. Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` helped to get online but the file could not be overwritten. So after a reboot I had exactly the same problem.

My workaround was:

1. `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`
2. `sudo service network-manager restart && service networking restart`

(after it there were the right DNS Server-IP's in the `/etc/resolv.conf` ; just ``` cat /etc/resolv.conf`` after ```sudo service network-manager restart && service networking restart` and look if it's right)

3. `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service`
4. reboot & enjoy. the resolv.conf's dns-addresses have been changed to the right ones.

p.s. don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` anymore. if you want to look if it has the right IP's, please use cat. otherwise it can happen, that after reboot you have `nameserver 127.0.0.1'` there again.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working around outside how **NetworkManager** and **resolvconf** work,

I just created/edited

```
 /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

with

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Then just run

```
resolvconf -u
```

to regenerate **/etc/resolv.conf**.
Just keep in mind that all network interfaces will see and try to use those, even offline ones.